# Having trouble with if and while loops when generating code

Tags: java, if-statement

This code asks for a score between 0-100. If the score is in between, it is added to the total and later used to calculate the average. The problem I am having is placing the if statement if the score is greater than 100, printing an illegal statement and asking the user to retype the number. When I put this if, in the while loop, I am getting an infinite number of illegal exceptions printed out. how do I fix this problem?

```
public class SentinalValuedControlledLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int studentCount = 1;
        double total = 0.0;
        double average;
        int score;

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        //title at top of output
        System.out.println("Sai Bharathula's Score Report");

        //read score for student
        System.out.printf("Enter a score (0 too 100, -1 to quit #%d:)", studentCount);
        score = stdin.nextInt();


        while(score !=-1) {
           //THIS IS THE IF STATEMENT I AM TALKING ABOUT THAT IS CAUSING ME TROUBLE 
            if(score >100){
                System.out.println("Illegal Score Try Again");
            }

            if(score >0 && score <= 100) {
               System.out.printf ("Enter a score (0 too 100, -1 to quit #%d:)", studentCount);
              score = stdin.nextInt();         
              studentCount++;  
            }
        }

    average = total / studentCount;
    System.out.printf ("\nThe average score for %d students is %8.2f\n",
                          studentCount, average);   

    }
}
```

Comment: If the number entered is greater than 100, you need to get a new number from the user.  You're not doing that, so `score` stays at that initial value forever, getting your code stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take input until your exit condition is satisfied (score == -1). And if your validation condition is violated (score < -1 or score > 100) you should prompt the user again for input.

Simplest way is to use a do-while loop and add a if-statement for validation:

```
int score = 0;
do {
        System.out.printf("Enter a score (0 too 100, -1 to quit #%d:)", studentCount);
        score = stdin.nextInt();         
        if (score > 100 || score < -1) {
            System.out.println("Illegal Score Try Again");
            continue;
        }
        studentCount++;
        total += score;
} while (score != -1);
```

P.S: You are not adding score to the running total in your loop. Added that.

Comment: Great. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you out. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a classical example of an endless loop.

Since this is clearly a HW assignment, let me try to help you this way:L

- When the score is greater than 100, is there any way that the loop can terminate?
- In other words: You enter the loop with a score of e.g. 101
- Then the "if" is checked
- Then the message is printed
- What happens next? The loop starts again.

I.e. you have to do something to "escape" the loop.

HTH